# Frequently asked questions in tags are no where to be found

Tags: support, new-nav, frequent-tab

I was just on another exchange (UX) doing some research (wizard editing - yes, that is an actual thing) and while looking at the wizard tag I clicked a button that I have used very often in the past. *frequent*

[image: "frequent" tab circled on a tagged-question page]

I clicked it without even thinking because it has become such a natural part of my workflow in the past. But once clicking I realized two things.

1. "frequent" is apparently the same as "sort by most links". I had no idea that was the case
2. "frequent" is not available in the new UI from this avenue. It must be manipulated through the hard to find (and also strangely named) "sort by most links" in the "popular" tab while then selecting "custom tags" from the dropdown of filter and then hand typing part of the tag, and then clicking on the tag itself.

I know that everything often needs more jQuery. But in this case, jQuery needs more frequent.

[image: dropdown of sort options, lacking "frequent"]

Answer (score -1):

It's still there, you need to go to https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=popular&show=alltime&sort=mostlinked

Comment: I see it in the popular tab. Out of curiosity, why have two different tabs where the primary difference is only two options? Wouldn't one tab with 5 options be better than two tabs with 3 options? It seems these are all very closely related topics that could just be grouped together. Further, why was frequent renamed to most linked? Is this causing a drop in traffic to that set of questions?